# Show $E(X^{\alpha}) = \int^{\infty}_{0} x^{\alpha}e^{-x} dx$ converges for $\alpha > -1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

How to prove that folloving integral converges(or that this expectation exists) for some $$\alpha$$ and in solutions it says integral converges if and only if $$ \alpha > -1 $$

$$E(X^{\alpha}) = \int^{\infty}_{0} x^{\alpha}e^{-x} dx$$

I tried just integrate it but cant´t solve it, any tips?

EDIT: I have issues with this type of exercises, havent never studied the formally...can anyone direct me to some literature or if this section of analysis has some special name?

Comment: you cant get a primitive that can be written with elementary functions. The integral is equivalent to $\Gamma(\alpha+1)$. Decompose the integral in it ranges $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ and study each case by separate. When the integrand approach zero it is finite, so it can be treated as a proper integral of Riemann in $(0,1)$. For $(1,\infty)$ you can make a change of variable that transform infinity to some finite quantity and repeat the analysis that you did for $(0,1)$

Answer (score 3):

As explained by Minz, since $x^a e^{-x}<e^{-\frac{x}2}$ for all large enough $x$, the integral $$\int_1^\infty x^a e^{-x}\mathrm dx$$ converges for each $a\in\mathbb R$.

I am going to address the other integral in some more detail. Note that for $x\in[0,1]$, we have $$e^{-1}\leq e^{-x}.$$ Therefore $$e^{-1}\int_0^1x^a\mathrm dx\leq\int_0^1x^a e^{-x}\mathrm dx.\tag{$\ast$}$$ For $a<-1$ we have $$\int_0^1x^a\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\searrow 0}\int_c^1x^a\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\searrow 0}\frac{1-c^{a+1}}{a+1}=\infty$$ and for $a=-1$ we have $$\int_0^1x^{-1}\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\searrow 0}\int_c^1x^{-1}\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\searrow 0}(-\log x)=\infty.$$ So the integral on the left hand side of $(*)$ is infinite and the original integral diverges for $a\leq-1$.

It remains to show that the integral converges for $a>-1$. By definition, we have $$\int_0^1x^ae^{-x}\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\searrow 0}\int_c^1x^ae^{-x}\mathrm dx,$$ so we wish to show that this limit exists. Let $$f(c)=\int_c^1x^ae^{-x}\mathrm dx.$$ The function $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is monotonically decreasing, since the integrand is positive. So for the limit to exist, it is sufficient to show that $f$ is bounded, as this will imply $$\lim_{c\searrow 0}f(c)=\sup_{c\in(0,1]} f(c).$$ To do this, remember that $$e^{-x}\leq1$$ holds for $x\in[0,1]$, so we have $$f(c)=\int_c^1x^ae^{-x}\mathrm dx\leq\int_c^1x^a\mathrm dx=\frac{1-c^{a+1}}{a+1}\leq\frac1{a+1}.$$ We have found an upper bound for $f$. Therefore the integral converges for $a>-1$.

**Remark.** The fact that the integrand is positive was crucial here. In general, to show that the integral converges, it is not enough to show that it is bounded. For instance, the integral $$\int_0^{1/\pi}\frac{\cos{\frac1x}}{x^2}\mathrm dx$$ is "bounded between $-1$ and $1$", but diverges, since the limit $$\lim_{c\searrow0}\int_c^{1/\pi}\frac{\cos{\frac1x}}{x^2}\mathrm dx=\lim_{c\searrow0}\sin\frac1c$$ does not exist.

To establish convergence in case of a less well-behaved integrand it is sometimes helpful to use the Cauchy condition for limits of functions.

Also, instead of establishing the existence of limits by hand, there are general criteria for the convergence of integrals which you might want to use.

Answer (score 1):

$x^\alpha e^{-x}<e^{-x/2}$ for sufficiently large $x$ hence $\int_1^\infty$ converges. As regards the integral $\int_0^1$ it converges if $\alpha >-1$ because $e^{-x}\sim 1$

Comment: Thanks, can you pleas explain first inequallity, where you bound integrand?

Comment: @econ, this inequallity is equivalent to $x^\alpha<e^{x/2}$ which in  turn is equivalent to $\alpha \ln x<x/2$

Comment: Thank you, I understanded this,but how can I prove this? I tried induction but get stuck at $\alpha ln(x+1) < \frac{x+1}{2}$. I also can`t prove that integral from 0 to 1 converges for $\alpha < -1$ , but can prove that exp(-x/2) converges, so thanks for this. I am really stuck at other queastions...can you pleas help me?

Comment: Simply calculate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\ln x}$ by L'Hopital's rule. The integral $\int_1^\infty e^{-x/2}dx=-2e^{-x/2}\bigg|_1^\infty=2e^{-1/2}$  by the Newton-Leibniz formula

Comment: Thanks for tip with inequality, I understand now that integral from 1 to $\infty$ converges, but don`t understand what to do  with integral from 0 to 1. Can you write out the proof?

Comment: As $e^{-1}\sim 1$ just discard this multiplier and integrate the remaining. And do not confuse $\alpha>-1$ with $\alpha<-1.$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 1} \int^{x}_{0} x^{\alpha} dx = \lim_{x\to 1} {\frac{x^{\alpha + 1}}{{\alpha} + 1}} < {\infty} $$ Is this what you meant?